# How to use purrr's map function to perform row-wise prop.tests and add results to the dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to solve the following problem in R: I have a dataframe with two variables (number of successes, and number of total trials).

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
 Success     N
    <dbl> <dbl>
1     28.   40.
2     12.   40.
3     22.   40.
4      8.   40.
```

I would like to perform a prop.test or binom.test on each row and add the resulting list to the dataframe (or certain elements of it, like the p-value and CIs).

Ideally, I would like to add a third column with the p-values and the CI-range. My attempts so far were painly unsuccessful. Here is a minimal coding example:

```
Success <- c( 38, 12, 27, 9)
N <- c( 50, 50, 50, 50)
df <- as.tibble( cbind(Success, N))


df %>%
  map( ~ prop.test, x = .$Success, n = .$N)
```

Doesn't give the desired result. Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Luise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a new column, you'd use @akrun's approach but sprinkle in a little `dplyr` and `broom` amongst the `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse) # for dplyr, purrr, tidyr & co.
library(broom)
    
analysis <- df %>%
  set_names(c("x","n")) %>% 
  mutate(result = pmap(., prop.test)) %>% 
  mutate(result = map(result, tidy))
```

From there that gives you the results in a tidy nested tibble.  If you want to just limit that to certain variables, you'd just follow the `mutate`/`map` applying functions to the nested frame, then unnest().

```
analysis %>% 
  mutate(result = map(result, ~select(.x, p.value, conf.low, conf.high))) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(result))

# A tibble: 4 x 5
      x     n   p.value conf.low conf.high
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 38.0   50.0 0.000407    0.615      0.865
2 12.0   50.0 0.000407    0.135      0.385
3 27.0   50.0 0.671       0.395      0.679
4  9.00  50.0 0.0000116   0.0905     0.319
```

Comment: Warning message: `cols` is now required.Please use `cols = c(result)`   unnest(cols=c("result"))

Answer (score 9):

We can use `pmap` after changing the column names with the arguments of 'prop.test'

```
pmap(setNames(df, c("x", "n")), prop.test)
```

---

Or using `map2`

```
map2(df$Success, df$N, prop.test)
```

---

The problem with `map` is that it is looping through each of the columns of the dataset and it is a `list` of `vector`s

```
df %>%
   map(~ .x)
#$Success
#[1] 38 12 27  9

#$N
#[1] 50 50 50 50
```

So, we cannot do `.x$Success` or `.x$N`

#### Update

As @Steven Beaupre mentioned, if we need to create new columns with p-value and confidence interval

```
res <- df %>%
        mutate(newcol = map2(Success, N, prop.test), 
            pval = map_dbl(newcol, ~ .x[["p.value"]]), 
            CI = map(newcol, ~ as.numeric(.x[["conf.int"]]))) %>% 
            select(-newcol) 
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#   Success     N      pval CI       
#    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <list>   
#1   38.0   50.0 0.000407  <dbl [2]>  
#2   12.0   50.0 0.000407  <dbl [2]>
#3   27.0   50.0 0.671     <dbl [2]>
#4    9.00  50.0 0.0000116 <dbl [2]>
```

The 'CI' column is a `list` of 2 elements, which can be `unnest`ed to make it a 'long' format data

```
res %>%
   unnest
```

---

Or create 3 columns

```
df %>% 
  mutate(newcol = map2(Success, N,  ~ prop.test(.x, n = .y) %>% 
                  {tibble(pvalue = .[["p.value"]],
                         CI_lower = .[["conf.int"]][[1]], 
                         CI_upper = .[["conf.int"]][[2]])})) %>%
  unnest
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  Success     N    pvalue CI_lower CI_upper
#    <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1   38.0   50.0 0.000407    0.615     0.865
#2   12.0   50.0 0.000407    0.135     0.385
#3   27.0   50.0 0.671       0.395     0.679
#4    9.00  50.0 0.0000116   0.0905    0.319
```

Comment: Handy tip: if you give `map` a string instead of a function it works as an extractor, so `pval = map_dbl(newcol, ~ .x[["p.value"]])` can actually be `pval = map_dbl(newcol, "p.value")`.

Answer (score 0):

The question mentions `prop.test` and `binom.test` but another alternative is `binom::binom.confint` which among other things is useful when estimating confidence intervals when you have zero successes, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82720/confidence-interval-around-binomial-estimate-of-0-or-1), [here](https://casual-inference.com/post/binom-confint/), and [here](https://www.wavedatalabs.com.au/posts/2023-03-13-choosing-the-right-binomial-confidence-interval/). If using this function, the following might be useful:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(binom)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(binom_test_var = list(binom.confint(x = Success, n = N, method = c("wilson")))) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(binom_test_var))
# # A tibble: 4 × 8
#   Success     N method     x     n  mean  lower upper
#     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      38    50 wilson    38    50  0.76 0.626  0.857
# 2      12    50 wilson    12    50  0.24 0.143  0.374
# 3      27    50 wilson    27    50  0.54 0.404  0.670
# 4       9    50 wilson     9    50  0.18 0.0977 0.308
```